# How to add addWindowListener to all the Panels when i using CardLayout?

Tags: java

I am trying to add `WindowListener` to all the panels in my application. When i close any panel, it will display some messages. I don't know where should i put the `WindowListener` and how to use the same.

```
public MainFrame(){

    this.cont= new Controller();

    this.setTitle("Expense Manager");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(null);

    this.card=new CardLayout();
    this.setLayout(this.card);

    this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
          public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            int confirmed = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
                "Are you sure you want to exit the program?", "Exit Program Message Box",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

            if (confirmed == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
              dispose();
            }
          }
        });

    this.pack();
    this.showLoginScreen();
    this.setVisible(true);


}
```

Comment: Two things - 1. I'm not sure the this would the correct approach and 2. If you're hoping that when `card.show` is called it will trigger a `WindowListener` event, then you'll be very disappointed.  I'm thinking that it would become the "controller"'s responsibility to ask each panel if they can be navigated away from, but that's me

Comment: Sorry, I am just new to java. I am trying to display messages after user close the windows. But as u know, i am using cardlayout to show different jpanels.

Comment: Then you only have one window, attach it to it

Comment: @MadProgrammer  I think the mainframe is the window, but it not work.

Comment: I did a five minute test and it works fine work me, then again, I don't have all your code - consider providing a runnable example which demonstrates your problem